# SQLite - How do I get rows of the same gender to have more chance and be sorted randomly

Tags: sqlite

How is the query used to get rows with a greater chance of gender being drawn randomly?
For example, I have the following data:

```
id    username     gender
1     brian        m
2     adam         m
3     chloe        f
4     andrian      m
5     amanda       f
```

Let's just say that I am male (m), then the lines that I might get are between 1, 2, and 4, where it is randomly selected, but it does not rule out I get 3 and 5.

I've tried using `RANDOM()` but it is completely random and there is no big chance for male gender.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM clients ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
```

Or I try `WHERE` so what you get is random rows but only with male gender, meaning that female gender doesn't get a chance at all.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE gender = 'm' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Please provide details on what you have tried and an MRE as described in the tag info for SQLite. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info You probably have a solution without the desired bias for females. Please show that.

Comment: without seeing your actual query it will be difficult to help you, common sense

Comment: oh, I'm so sorry

Comment: i just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to assign weights to the genders like `70%` for male and `30%` for female in the random selection, then one way to do it is with a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
ORDER BY RANDOM() * (CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 0.7 ELSE 0.3 END) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks, I don't understand about ```CASE``` hehe. Once again, thank you so much

Comment: @SuluhS for each row of the table the random generated number is multiplied by 0.7 when the row contains gender = 'm' or by 0.3 gender = 'f' so the rows contains gender = 'm' will have higher probability to by at the top of the list.